# Is there a negative regular expression in Python (negation)?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say that I want to make a RE that describes all integers. By definition the expression is:

```
(+|-)?[0-9]+
```

But the definition also matches these numbers : `+0, -0, 0045`

The `0045` occasion can probably be solved using a lookback expression but how can I excusively exclude the `+0` and `-0` strings from the RE. I thought the syntax for this was `^(+0|-0`) but that's probably a RE syntax for an other framework not Pythons'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then the case of zero can be handled separately. Regular expression for zero or non-zero numbers:

```
0|[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*
```

The assumptions were:

- no superfluous heading zeroes.
- no sign before zero
- superfluous plus sign allowed before non-zero numbers.

Outside a character group (with square brackets), the symbol `^` means the start of the string or line depending on the flag setting of `re.MULTILINE`.